# Create a File with Touch on a specific Directory

Tags: shell, directory, filenames

I want a create a file with a specific extension(.done). I am using the command touch. Something Like:

```
touch `basename $UNZIPFILE`".done"
```

It's creating the file but in current directory. I want to create this file in a specific directory. 
Is there a option to provide the directory ?

I checked : http://ss64.com/bash/touch.html , but could not figure out.

I can think of one option is before this command I can do a 
`cd requiredDIR`

Is  there any other way, I can specify the Directory on the same command, so that I dont have to change the Directory?

Comment: I don't understand the question: why aren't you running `touch "$UNZIPFILE.done"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basename remove the directory part. You may get it back with command `dirname`

```
touch "$(dirname "$UNZIPFILE")/$(basename "$UNZIPFILE").done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
touch ./directoryYouWantFileIn/Whateveryouwantfilenamed.whateverExtension
```

I think you need full path of where you want it made.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that your answer is essentially the same as the accepted answer, only with a hard-coded filename.